# Object Behaviour

Tags: c#

Can anyone explain the behaviour of the below code. The output of the below code is string "str" and i's value is 100.

But why is it so? After setting object c1 = null, why isn't it null?

```
public class Class1
{
    public int i;
    public Class1()
    {
        i = 10;
    }    

    public string method1()
    {
        return "str";
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    public void method2(Class1 c1)
    {
        c1.i = 100;
        c1 = null;
    }
}

    void main()
    {
        Class1 c1 = new Class1();
        Class2 c2 = new Class2();
        c2.method2(c1);
        Response.Write(c1.method1());
        Response.Write(c1.i.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pass-by-reference/pass-by-value thing. [Javaranch Camp site stories: Pass By Value Please](http://www.javaranch.com/campfire/StoryPassBy.jsp) explains it very well. I know the above link is for Java, and this is a C# question, but the same thing happens (unless the "ref" keyword is used).

Comment: And here's a good C#-specific article: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: @LukeH your article is a bit waffly/academic. I like the java version more.

Answer (score 5):

When you call `method2(Class1 c1)` you are passing a copy of the reference to the object, not the object itself (or the reference to it).  When you set `c1 = null` you are setting the copy of the reference to be null, not the object.

You can get the behaviour you expect by changing your method signature to this:

`method2(ref Class1 c1)`

Answer (score 4):

In C#, references are passed by value. That is, `method2` receives a copy of the value of the  reference to `c1`.

In `method2` setting `c1 = null` affects the local copy of the reference only.

See [this article for more info](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html)

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully a simple edit of your code can show you why:

```
public class Class1
{
    public int i;
    public Class1()
    {
        i = 10;
    }    

    public string method1()
    {
        return "str";
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    public void method2(Class1 myLocalReference)
    {
        myLocalReference.i = 100;
        myLocalReference = null;
    }
}

void main()
{
    Class1 c1 = new Class1();
    Class2 c2 = new Class2();
    c2.method2(c1);
    Response.Write(c1.method1());
    Response.Write(c1.i.ToString());
}
```

I think that shows clearly that the reference used in Class2.method2 isn't the same as that used in main. `c1` is declared in main, when used as a parameter in the method call `c2.method2(c1);` the reference to your Class1 instances is copied into a new local value called `myLocalReference`. You then set `myLocalReference = null;` and within method2 you would find that `Response.Write(myLocalReference.method1());` or `Response.Write(myLocalReference.i.ToString());` would fail appropriately. When method2 exits the local reference `myLocalReference` goes out of scope and you return to main where the c1 reference exists and is unchanged so the subsequent Response.Write methods succeed.